# What design pattern to use when object create multiple time and share to different file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

enter code hereI have case i needs 2 connector MongoClient. first client to connect to local mongodb server. 2nd client to connect to remote mongodb. 2 client inside 1 file `database-connector.js`. is it right or wrong in this ways? what the correct ways in this problem?

```
class CatchError {
    static error: string | unknown;

    static save(error: string | unknown) {
        this.error = error;

        const re = new RegExp('ECONNREFUSED', 'i')

        if (re.test(error.message)) {
            // fs.write('system.error.log')
        }
    }
}


class DBClient {
    client: MongoClient;

    constructor(url: string, config: Partial<MongoClientOptions>) {
        this.client = new MongoClient(url, config)
    }

    async connect() {
        try {
            this.client = await this.client.connect();
            return this.client;
        } catch(error) {
            CatchError.parse(error)
        }
    }
```

}

```
// for entire data application 
export const localDBClient = initializeDBConnection("mongodb://localhost");

// only for authentication to access application
export const remoteDBClient = initializeDBConnection("mongodb+srv://se132.aws-slcuster.com");
```

gui.js

```
import { remoteDBClient } from "database-connector.js";
// use client //
```

model.js

```
import { localDBClient } from "database-connector.js";
// use client //
```

Comment: Yes you can do that. Only downside is that if you want to use the gui without the model (or the model without the gui) you still have initialised both db connections.

Comment: @Bergi in your perspective, what i can improve from this problem? or just me that expect is still theres something wrong. sometime i over thinking, and think. it still theres better ways than current. like + and downside.

Comment: @Bergi i asks cause i have a strict rule that i apply to myself to translate problem into consistent structure code, if a object definition needs to share. i should create in seperate files. like `common/database-connector.js` contain definition. the other should contain the object use. if object that use into other object as single entity, singleton pattern. its not make confuse. ex common problem, it only have single client either connect to local or remote directly.  so i still thinking, should i share as object or as connection directly.

Comment: or i need to create middle man that hold all initalize connection. then, i just import from that file. ex, `database-connector.js` contains implementation error and everything. in other file like `collection-database-connector.js`. i initialize all connection. then inside `model.js` instead import `database-connector.js` i will import `collection-database-connector.js`. what u think?

Comment: So is this actually a problem in your application? If no, then no need to solve it by applying an inflexible, fixed structure. "*if a object definition needs to share, i should create in seperate files*" - so does the object actually need to be shared? The example you've given in the three snippets does not indicate that.

Comment: @Bergi i just make it simple in this case, but it still explain what the problem, in real case each connector implementatiion, let say nodejs mongodbclient package. it lack of error handling. i check already, the result of error not consistent. so i need to wrap it again into new object. thats why to make it simple, i wrap it into function. exactly inside that function there're other implementation, like error handling, where to save the error and in waht format. so make it simple just think that definition object.

Comment: Don't confuse the function with the objects it creates. `initializeDBConnection` that does all the error handling etc absolutely should be shared, and put in the separate module. However the `localDBClient` and `remoteDBClient` (singleton?) objects might not need to.

Comment: @Bergi when i means a object definition. its not means an object. but the definition. or i think i wrong to explains. its better to use create object multiple times in different file.

Comment: @Bergi i update question, make it more clear what exactly inside `database-connector.js`. real implementation error will be long to put here. but what the design pattern to create object multiple time for different object use case. ex, for gui object and model object. at this point, i think this aleady clear. share definition object should in own file. i know in programming, some problem can solve in thousand ways. like meme, bird exactly fly with wing, but in programming, bird can fly with head as propeller. this's called bad design, but the program still works.